# Stop WD My Passport SSD going to sleep on Asus Vivo X513EA w. Win 10. NO power options shown in win 10

Tags: windows-10, usb-c

Asus Vivo X513EA running Windows 10 all updates installed.

I have two new WD My Passport SSD's, 1x2TB & 1x1TB, both only a couple of weeks old.

I connect them via the USB-c port and within 20 seconds of nothing being read or written to either of them, they go to sleep. If I want to open a file that's store on them, or want to copy a file to them it takes 15 - 20 seconds for them to wake up. This is with the PSU plugged in,

I have checked via the battery icon and there is no option to create a custom power plan with anything other than the most basic power options. There is no setting available to turn off putting the usb ports to sleep.

As per the image below, if I click on Change advanced power options, again there is no option to set USB sleep settings.

If I go to Device Manager > USB Root Hub > Power Management
and untick "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
when I reboot my laptop the tick has been added back in.

Its driving me mad.[image]

Comment: Do these behave differently on a different computer? Have you checked the power settings of the USB C ports in Device Manager?

Comment: Have you tried changing Generic USB Hub? (Not Root Hub)  I changed power on that and the change (do not save power) survived a reboot.  Try that,